# How to use "sencha ant resources" for development environment?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I want to generate my resources with the command "sencha ant resources". Currently the files will be located at "..\build\production...".
But while development I'd need this files at "..\build\development..." but I can't figure out how to achieve this. Is there a property to run the command in development environment or something like this?

Maybe you can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you already tried it with development as an option? like described here: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html - i can not confirm that it will work because i only use sencha app build ENV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I had to type `sencha ant development resources` to set the environment correctly.